# How to login into google account

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication

I'm trying to login into Google accounts in a C# WPF application.

I have a window with two textboxes called `tb_nick` for nickname and `tb_pass` for password. I want that if I enter Google username and password and I press login I'll connect to my account with a message that says "connection OK" or something else.

Can anyone help me please? I'm new in programming.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! What have you tried yourself? Please provide some _relevant_ code snippets that showcase your effort in trying to connect to "Google accounts". =)

Comment: i haven't any code for the login phase, i've tried but unseccessfully. can someone please write down the code for me? as i told i'm new in programming and the oauth or openID lib are quite difficult for me. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps  https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID

Stackoverflow is a good example. You can use OpenID provided by Google to sign in.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can do it by using the google API. 
[Google APLI GMail Auth](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-settings/auth?hl=de)

On https://developers.google.com/ you will find many informations how you can use google from an external Program.

Answer (score 0):

For enabling users to login from your application you should use [ClientLogin](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/auth/clientlogin)  but as you can see it's part of the old Google Api library Gdata. You still can find it and you can use such authentication but i advise you not becouse has several security drawbacks(and this is probably the reason for which Google took it away). Instead use [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2).